# AWS lambda update-function-code with jar package via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I'm trying to update my lambda function code with jar from my local machine via AWS CLI.
The aws lambda has commands to update function code for zip file but not for jar.
I can upload by using s3 bucket, but I need to update from local itself.

I know following are the way to update from S3 bucket and for **zip:**

1. aws lambda update-function-code --function-name
   --s3-bucket  --s3-key
2. aws lambda update-function-code --function-name
   --zip-file "fileb://"

I want to ask is there similar command exist for uploading jar as  well?

Comment: No. Just zip it and call `aws lambda update-function-code`.

Comment: Thank MaikaY, but then it doesn't identify the Handler class. If I change the extension from zip to jar then it works

Comment: Did you check the documentation? [Creating a .zip Deployment Package (Java)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html)

Comment: Yes I checked the document. But from starting we are using java jar. I can switch to zip. But I don't want. But then I guess AWS doesn't provide much option

Answer (score 26):

You're probably missing the "fileb://" part for the jar.

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-lambda-name --zip-file fileb://./target/my-lambda-jar.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but if you read the question carefully, I'm asking about upload of jar package not zip file. I have gone through the documentation, I know how to upload zip but didn't find anything for jar

Comment: The example I gave is for loading a jar. It just uses the zip parameter. If you look at the file extension, it’s a jar.

Comment: Hi do we still need the 'fileb://' bit for parameter `--s3-bucket`

Answer (score 1):

run this command:

`aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-lambda-name --zip-file fileb://./target/my-lambda-jar.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: What is that ./target?